# Javascript object throwing type error

Tags: javascript, object

I'm having trouble getting a simple bit of javascript to work. I get this error message:

```
TypeError: tableKeyPerInd1.getTotal is not a function
tempHold = tableKeyPerInd1.getTotal();
```

From this code:

```
 tableKeyPerInd1 = new table("keyPerformanceIndicators");
 console.log(tableKeyPerInd1.table);
 tempHold = tableKeyPerInd1.getTotal();
 console.log(tempHold);
 function table(TableName){

  this.table=TableName;

  function getTotal()
  {
   this.runningTotal = 0;
   columns = new Array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
   for(var t=0; t<columns.length ;t+=1){
    this.runningTotal += $('SupplementaryExamKPI'+columns[t]) + $('DiabeticScreeningKPI'+columns[t])+$('LvaKPI'+columns[t]);
   }
  }
 }
```

How can I fix this?

---

I thought it might help others if I posted the complete solution.  I've also added into this solution how to create objects on the fly.  So this creates a total and it creates individual objects for each day  i.e this.Mon, this.Tue etc

```
 tableKeyPerInd1 = new table("keyPerformanceIndicators");
 columns = new Array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");

 function table(TableName){

  this.table=TableName;
  this.runningTotal = 0;
  this.Mon = 0;
  this.getTotal =   function getTotal()
  {
   this.runningTotal = 0;

   for(var t=0; t<columns.length ;t+=1){
    var supexam = Number.from($('SupplementaryExamKPI'+columns[t]).get('value'));
    var diabeticscreen = Number.from($('DiabeticScreeningKPI'+columns[t]).get('value'));
    var lva = Number.from($('LvaKPI'+columns[t]).get('value'));
    this.runningTotal += supexam + diabeticscreen+lva;
    this[columns[t]] = supexam + diabeticscreen+lva;
   }
   return ;
  }
 }
```

Comment: `getTotal` is a private function. If you change it to `this.getTotal = function () {...` you'll be able to call it.

Comment: thanks Andy worked a treat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
function getTotal()
```

try the following

```
this.getTotal = function () {
    this.runningTotal = 0;
    columns = new Array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
    for(var t=0; t<columns.length ;t+=1){
        this.runningTotal += $('SupplementaryExamKPI'+columns[t]) +                         $('DiabeticScreeningKPI'+columns[t])+$('LvaKPI'+columns[t]);
    }
};
```